# Etymological connection between 門 and 円?

Tags: kanji, etymology, history

I'm curious if there's any historical link between the kanji for "gate", 門{かど}, and the kanji for "circle" or "yen", 円{えん}. If 門 is gate, 円 looks like a closed gate. Am I being whimsical and seeing patterns in the wind, or is there a substantive link here?

Please use furigana when writing kanji; I'm a beginning student and don't know many kanji.

Comment: They are not related. 円 was originally written as 圓.

Comment: Okay. What prompted the change?

Comment: Hope someone will translate this for you. http://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/wp/2010/03/18/%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%EF%BC%9A%E9%9F%93%E5%9B%BD%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8A%E9%87%91%E3%82%82%E3%80%8C%E5%86%86%E3%80%8D%E3%81%84/

Comment: @LeoKing I believe that the switch from 圓 to 円 was part of the post-war [transition from kyuujitai to shinjitai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai), in which a large number of characters changed forms (not just 圓).

Comment: This suspicion is off the mark. Why not just hypothesize that 門　is just 月cut vertically in half, with the halves each closed off by a stroke.

Comment: You're telling me there's a correct misinterpretation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the question comments, the kanji 円 was originally 圓.  The nutshell version of the article Yang Muye linked is that monks developed a shorthand version of 圓 that looked like a box with a vertical line through it: [image: shorthand version of 圓 that looks like a box with a vertical line through it]. Over time, the shape of the surrounding box changed, likely due to the same anatomical and mechanical processes that inform any change in handwriting. [image] became [image], and then that became the modern simplified *shinjitai* character 円.

門, meanwhile, is a pictogram of a gate.  You might run across alternative form 鬥, but otherwise, this character is much more straightforward, both in semantic development and graphical evolution.

Ultimately, the resemblance between 円 and 門 is purely accidental, and has much more to do with the constraints placed on kanji shapes and the kinds of strokes used in handwriting.

Comment: I know Japanese doesn't use「鬥」anymore, but it originally meant たたかう - the replacement of「鬥」with「門」happened in many characters because they looked similar, and hence why these characters had something to do with *fighting* / *noisy*. These characters have no semantic connection with「門」, so be careful in calling them variants.